„viele dieser" vs „viele von diesen"?
Ich habe mal einen Aufsatz geschrieben, in dem ich die Phrase

viele von diesen

verwendet habe.  Die Phrase wurde bis auf

viele dieser

korrigiert.  Also wurde „von" mit dem Genitiv ersetzt.  Ist die Verwendung von „von" in diesem Kontext nicht erlaubt, oder ist es einfach stilistisch besser, den Genitiv zu benutzen?  ChatGPT meint, dass, wenn auch „von" in diesem Kontext benutzt werden kann (zumindest umgangssprachlich),  der Genitiv jedoch die korrekte Wahl ist.  Aber ChatGPT kann man nicht immer vertrauen, also wollte ich eure Meinung dazu.
Gelten die Antworten auf diese Fragen auch für „einige", "wenige", usw?  Ich nehme an, das ist der Fall.

Es gibt im Deutschen den sogenannten "Genitivus partitivus", den Genitiv des Teils. Diese Form kommt aus dem Lateinischen und bezeichnet eine Gesamtheit, von der ein Teil genannt wird:

ein Glas reinsten Wassers.

Von allem Wasser, das es gibt, ist das hier ein Glas (voll) mit reinstem solchen.
Auf Latein wäre eine entsprechende Formulierung etwa:

multum operae (viel Mühe, wörtlich "viel der Mühe")

Diese Form war früher häufiger verbreitet und während "ein Glas reinsten Wassers" noch durchaus natürlich klingt, klingt "viel der Mühe" mittlerweile ungewöhnlich und ein wenig altertümelnd. Aber selbst das erste Beispiel kann auch mit:

ein Glas reinstes Wasser

ausgedrückt werden.
Soviel zu dem Spannungsfeld, in welchem die Formulierung in der Frage steht. Tatsächlich ist das eine Entwicklung, die zwar Formulierungen wie die obigen Beispiele bereits erfaßt hat, vor "viele von diesen" aber noch Halt macht. Wahrscheinlich (wenn man die Sprachentwicklung extrapoliert) wird irgendwann in der Zukunft "viele von diesen" als normal empfunden werden und "viele dieser" - wie die anderen Beispiele - zwar nicht falsch aber merkwürdig erscheinen. Das allerdings ist Spekulation.
Tatsächlich kommt noch ein eher subjektiver Umstand dazu: viele halbgebildete Deutschsprecher halten den Genitiv für "eleganter" und "gebildeter" als die anderen Fälle. Das fängt bei Leuten wie Bastian Sick an, der seinen Lebensunterhalt damit verdient, einerseits den "Tod des Genitivs" zu beweinen und andererseits bestimmte Stilfehler apodiktisch vorzuschreiben. Das Problem ist aber keineswegs auf ihn und seinesgleichen beschränkt.
Vielmehr ist es so, daß, beginnend im späten Mitttelhochdeutsch bzw. frühen Neuhochdeutsch, der Genitiv eine absurde Blüte erlebt hat, die mittlerweile (seit etwa Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts) im Abflauen begriffen ist. Das betrifft insbesondere den adverbialen Genitiv, der vermutlich zum Aussterben verdammt ist. Ein genaueres Eingehen auf dieses Problem  würde vermutlich den Rahmen sprengen, ich kann dazu allerdings das Buch "Deutsch für Dichter und Denker" von Daniel Scholten als weiterführende Lektüre empfehlen.

In den DWDS Gegenwartskorpora sieht der Trend eher gegenläufig aus, mit einer merkwürdigen Mode in den 2010er Jahren.

@ccprog Was ist zwischen 2016 und 2019 geschehen, dass „viele dieser" so stark versickert?

Ab 2003 veröffentlicht Bastian Sick seine Zwiebelfisch-Kolumne, aus der dann sechs Bücher mit dem Titel "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod" werden, mit Millionenauflage...

@Cerulean ...ah, ich habe den Kalauer zuerst glatt übersehen. Der letzte der sechs Bände erschien 2015.
